# 404 Not Found Could not find asset web/index.html in package polymer_snippet

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a working app prior to upgrading to the current polymer 0.16 and the current paper-element and core-element packages. Now when I run my index.html, I receive the following errors.

**browser output**

```
404 Not Found
Could not find asset web/index.html in package polymer_snippet.
```

**console output**

```
Serving polymer_snippet web on http://localhost:8080
Build error:
Transform polymer (PolymerBootstrapTransformer) on polymer_snippet|web/index.html threw error: Bad state: No element
dart:collection/list.dart 133                                         Object&ListMixin.firstWhere
package:initialize/transformer.dart 452                               InitializerData.annotationNode
package:web_components/build/html_import_annotation_recorder.dart 30  HtmlImportAnnotationRecorder.shouldApply
package:initialize/transformer.dart 279                               _BootstrapFileBuilder._buildNewEntryPoint.<fn>
dart:collection/list.dart 127                                         Object&ListMixin.firstWhere
package:initialize/transformer.dart 279                               _BootstrapFileBuilder._buildNewEntryPoint
package:initialize/transformer.dart 195                               _BootstrapFileBuilder.run
package:initialize/transformer.dart 35                                generateBootstrapFile
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 32                   generateWebComponentsBootstrap
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_bootstrap.dart 55                   PolymerBootstrapTransformer.apply.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1155                                             _RootZone.runUnary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 484                                       _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
dart:async/future_impl.dart 567                                       _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 550                                       _Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1155                                             _RootZone.runUnary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 484                                       _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
dart:async/future_impl.dart 567                                       _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 358                                       _Future._completeWithValue
dart:async/future_impl.dart 412                                       _Future._asyncComplete.<fn>
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 41                                 _asyncRunCallbackLoop
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 48                                 _asyncRunCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 96                              _runPendingImmediateCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 143                             _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

dart:collection                                                       Object&ListMixin.firstWhere
package:initialize/transformer.dart 452                               InitializerData.annotationNode
package:web_components/build/html_import_annotation_recorder.dart 30  HtmlImportAnnotationRecorder.shouldApply
package:initialize/transformer.dart 279                               _BootstrapFileBuilder._buildNewEntryPoint.<fn>
dart:collection                                                       Object&ListMixin.firstWhere
package:initialize/transformer.dart 279                               _BootstrapFileBuilder._buildNewEntryPoint
package:initialize/transformer.dart 195                               _BootstrapFileBuilder.run
package:initialize/transformer.dart 35                                generateBootstrapFile
package:web_components/build/web_components.dart 32                   generateWebComponentsBootstrap
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_bootstrap.dart 55                   PolymerBootstrapTransformer.apply.<fn>.<fn>
dart:isolate                                                          _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
Build completed with 1 errors.
[web] GET /index.html => Could not find asset polymer_snippet|web/index.html.
[web] GET /favicon.ico => polymer_snippet|web/favicon.ico
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
  Copyright (c) 2014, <your name>. All rights reserved. Use of this source code
  is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
-->

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
  <title>polymer_snippet</title>

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Web Starter Kit">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

  <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/touch/ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF">

  <!-- example of using a paper element -->
  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/roboto.html">

  <!-- example of your own custom element -->
  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_snippet/main_app.html">
  <link rel="import" href='../lib/main_app.html'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <link href='packages/core_elements/core_icon.html'  rel='import'>
  <link href='packages/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg/bwu_fontawesome_iconset_svg.html' rel='import' >
  <link href='packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/emojione_emoticons.html'  rel='import'>
  <link href='packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/emojione_dingbats.html'  rel='import'>
  <link href='packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/emojione_enclosed_characters.html'  rel='import'>
  <link href='packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/emojione_transport_and_map.html'  rel='import'>
  <link href='packages/bwu_emojione_iconset_svg/emojione_uncategorized.html'  rel='import'>

</head>

<body unresolved>
  <bwu-fontawesome-iconset-svg></bwu-fontawesome-iconset-svg>
  <emojione-emoticons></emojione-emoticons>
  <emojione-dingbats></emojione-dingbats>
  <emojione-enclosed-characters></emojione-enclosed-characters>
  <emojione-transport-and-map></emojione-transport-and-map>
  <emojione-uncategorized></emojione-uncategorized>  <main-app></main-app>

  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Questions**
- Is polymer 0.16 backward compatible with 0.15?
-Or is it that I will have to use @HtmlImport instead of the previos  styles?

Comment: It should be compatible. There were already one or two updates with bug fixes. If you have the most recent and still doesn't work report the issue.

Comment: I just tried it with gitbacklog and got crazy things happening so reverted back to 0.15. I didn't have time to look into it but there are definitely backward compatibility issues

Comment: After many attempts of installation it is working. I found that I had to use the popup menu update and get as the command line update and get hangs the application.

Comment: This happens occasionally when I introduce a change, esp an error, into an application I'm developing in WebStorm. I also see in on the command line. When restarting `pub serve`, the app again runs normally. Seems like it happened in Dart 0.12 and now in 0.13 with Dartium. Sometimes there's a msg about failing to inline an import.